# Is there a command line flag to disable JavaScript source maps for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, karma-runner, source-maps, google-chrome-flags

Edit: [I opened a new issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=781648).

---

Our project uses TypeScript compiled to JavaScript. When debugging automated unit tests in Karma, I want to disable JavaScript source maps and stick to debugging the compiled code.

I know how to do this from the browser settings but the change expires when I close the browser, so I'm looking for a way to disable it programmatically.

[Disable source maps in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/how-do-you-disable-source-maps-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Chrome accepts [other flags](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) from the command line (e.g. --no-sandbox). Is there a flag or similar means to disable source maps?

Comment: Based on the Chromium flags list https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ it seems there isn't any flags to disable the JavaScript Source map files :(

Comment: Here is an open issue requesting exactly what we are looking for: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=534874

Comment: The list of command line switches linked above contains a flag called `--devtools-flags` "Passes command line parameters to the DevTools front-end"
Maybe this is used in combination with some other flag?

Comment: There is a workaround in the reported issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=781648#c4

Comment: For now, try disabling creation of source maps from your bundler?

Comment: found this link to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: @user46194 the link is already in the question.

Answer (score 1):

on `webpack.config.js`

add `devtool: false`

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage }) => {
  // If production JavaScript and CSS build
  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
    // Turn off source maps
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      devtool: false,
    })
  }
};
```

or

You can pass compiler options inside every loader query string

```
loadWhatEVer?sourceMap=false
```

Comment: Ah. Nice idea in general: don't serve source maps when running the tests.