# why inspections showing scss file instead of bootstrap.css?

Tags: bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

When I do inspect element on one the row div it shows the element belongs to `_grid.scss` instead of `bootstrap.css`. And even the column in the row are not displaying correctly as it should be using bootstrap. Can someone clear this confusion?

I don't have any file in my css named as _grid.scss and the path it is referring to is empty as well.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

There are some default SCSS available in bootstrap. [More Information](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove bootstrap.css.map that means source map.

You can read more about source maps there https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0

Alternatively  you can disable in your inspector tool settings. e.g. in chrome: [How do you disable source maps in chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/how-do-you-disable-source-maps-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score -1):

Remove bootstrap.css.map that means source map.

You can read more about source maps there https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0

Alternatively you can disable in your inspector tool settings. e.g. in chrome: How do you disable source maps in chrome developer tools?