# css not taking css from .scss file

Tags: css, node.js, angular, sass, single-page-application

Not sure what am I missing...

I did try with css and scss and different combinations in .scss file. Still I don't see(in Inspect Element) it is taking the css from bootstrap.

Yes, I do have bootstrap css and scss files in the corresponding path.

angular.json

```
   "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

styles.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

@import "styles-variables.scss";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";
```

[image]

My Other App looks fine
[image]

somemore information, if that can give any clue. Not sure if it is because of mat-side-nav
[image]

Comment: I'm confused. You can see the css for `form-group` and `col-sm-12` on the right, no?

Comment: But that is coming from grid.scss. isn't it supposed to come from bootstrap ?

Comment: just add ../ to styles array like so 
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" instead of "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" and you do not need to add the sass packages to styles.scss. you either add the scss imports to styles.scss or to the styles array in angular.json

Answer (score 2):

To use **Bootstrap** styles in your application you need:

1. At first, you need to install Bootstrap:  `npm install –save bootstrap`
2. You should add import in `styles.scss`:

   ```
   @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
   ```
3. Add into `angular.json` file declaration of styles:

   ```
   ...
   "styles": [
         "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "src/styles.scss"
   ],
   ...
   ```

Comment: I don't see the a "dist" directory in ~bootstrap directory. I only see 'scss' directory, and that has bootstrap-grid.scss and bootstrap-reboot.scss

Comment: @SK. it looke like Bootstrap is installed incorrectly. So try to uninstall `npm uninstall bootstrap` and then install `npm install –save bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to import these line of code

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Since you already include the css file in your angular.json. With your current code you will have redundant code

Answer (score 1):

The styles *are* actually coming from the bootstrap.min.css, but you're browser inspector is showing the SASS source map.

Learn more: [why inspections showing scss file instead of bootstrap.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665012/why-inspections-showing-scss-file-instead-of-bootstrap-css)

Learn how to disable the SASS map in the inpsection tools: 
[Disable source maps in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools)

Comment: you are right. I just realized. But not getting why it is not showing as it should be. My other app is perfectly fine. Added a screenshot from my other app. Any idea please...

Comment: Why are you including both the SCSS and CSS in the angular.json styles?

Comment: I tried with only css and only .scss, then I tried with both