# Getting 404 quill.min.js.map error with Primefaces 8

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am using primefaces texteditor and primefaces-extension ckeditor both on the same page.

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8080/XX/javax.faces.resource/texteditor/quill.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore that error.  It is because PF TExtEditor uses QuillJS and it has this line in its JS.

```
//# sourceMappingURL=quill.min.js.map
```

And that file does not exist because PF does not include it. the browser Dev Tools just attempt to load it to help you debug.

Disable source map checks in Chrome: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Open%20Developer%20Tools%2C%20go%20to,under%20the%20%22Sources%22%20settings.&text=You%20can%20double%20click%20line,files%20to%20unminified%20output%20files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Open%20Developer%20Tools%2C%20go%20to,under%20the%20%22Sources%22%20settings.&text=You%20can%20double%20click%20line,files%20to%20unminified%20output%20files).

Comment: can I stop this error from appearing on the browser console?

Comment: Looks like this will do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Open%20Developer%20Tools%2C%20go%20to,under%20the%20%22Sources%22%20settings.&text=You%20can%20double%20click%20line,files%20to%20unminified%20output%20files.