# Typescript gives error for its own compilation

Tags: typescript, webpack, bind, ts-loader

My code:

```
addMouseOverListenerForNavItems() {
    this.navList.addEventListener('mouseover', this.mouseOverListener.bind(this));
}

mouseOverListener(e) {
    const closestNavItem: HTMLElement = e.target.closest(".js-mainbar__navitem");
    clearTimeout(this.closeTimer);
    this.openTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.openFlyout(closestNavItem);

    }, this.flyoutDelayMs);
}
```

Compiled code by typescript:

```
Menu.prototype.mouseOverListener = function (e) {
    var _this = this;
    var closestNavItem = e.target.closest(".js-mainbar__navitem");
    clearTimeout(this.closeTimer);
    this.openTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        _this.openFlyout(closestNavItem);
    }, this.flyoutDelayMs);
};
```

The error:

60:13  error    Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias

59 and 60.line =

```
Menu.prototype.mouseOverListener = function (e) {
    var _this = this;
```

What should I do to fix this error? I think I have used arrow function properly.

[image]

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports =  {
parser:  '@typescript-eslint/parser',  // Specifies the ESLint parser
extends:  [
  'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',  // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
],
parserOptions:  {
  ecmaVersion:  2018,  // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
  sourceType:  'module',  // Allows for the use of imports
},
rules:  {
    "curly": 1,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [0],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": [0],
    "ordered-imports": [0],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": [0],
    "max-len": [1, 120],
    "new-parens": 1,
    "no-bitwise": 1,
    "no-cond-assign": 1,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 1,
    "func-style": ["error", "declaration", { "allowArrowFunctions": true }],
    "semi": 1,
    "no-var": 0
},
};
```

Errors at console

[image]

Comment: Are you somehow passing in previously generated javascript files into your transpiler / linter? The checks should only be applied on the typescript files so what you are describing is strange. Can you please explicate when you see this error? What command did you run?

Comment: I see it at chrome console when I run "npm start". I have added exclude parameter at tsconfig.json after ur suggestion:   

"exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist", "src/**/*.js"]
still did not work.

Comment: The error comes from linter as you can see

Comment: I have added these # Ignore built files
./build/*
./dist/*
to .eslintignore. still giving these errors.

Comment: Is it normal that compiled javascript file is named as menu.ts? (I have added screenshot above)

Comment: For the menu.ts part, you disable source maps for a test, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: @tevemadar I still see the errors at chrome console :( (I added new ss)

Comment: Oh, it wasn't about solving anything, it was about seeing if the compiled script is really called ```menu.ts``` or not.

Comment: enforce: "pre" has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding

```
enforce: "pre"
```

to the webpack.

To be safe, you can use enforce: 'pre' section to check source files, not modified by other loaders (like babel-loader):

Source: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader