# How does this switch statement work? The case values appear to be undefined in the debugger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, switch-statement

I'm trying to understand how this code works, because it seems like it should not, **but it does work.**

Is this some TypeScript magic I'm not understanding? React magic? How does this work if the cases are not strings, but imported values which appear as `undefined`?

###### [Code source](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog/blob/0df53e3ff7285ccf8bd3c1657a71d92405cba17f/src/Container.tsx#L63-L90)

```js
import DialogTitle, { DialogTitleProps } from "./Title";
import DialogDescription, { DialogDescriptionProps } from "./Description";
import DialogButton, { DialogButtonProps } from "./Button";

// ....

  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (typeof child === "object" && child !== null && "type" in child) {
      switch (child.type) {
        case DialogTitle: // DialogTitle is undefined in the debugger when hovered
          titleChildrens.push(child as TitleElement);
          return;
        case DialogDescription: // DialogDescription is undefined in the debugger when hovered
          descriptionChildrens.push(child as DescriptionElement);
          return;
        case DialogButton: // DialogButton is undefined in the debugger when hovered
          if (Platform.OS === "ios" && buttonChildrens.length > 0) {
            buttonChildrens.push(
              <View
                style={[
                  verticalButtons
                    ? styles.buttonSeparatorVertical
                    : styles.buttonSeparatorHorizontal,
                  buttonSeparatorStyle,
                ]}
              />
            );
          }
          buttonChildrens.push(child as ButtonElement);
          return;
      }
    }
    otherChildrens.push(child);
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You misunderstand. The code is functional and not mine. I need to understand _WHY_ it functions, because it sure looks like it shouldn't - but it does.

Comment: I think the debugger is misleading you. Try adding in a `console.log(DialogTitle`) statement, and i suspect you will get a value that is not `undefined`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. `ReferenceError`. I've added the image to the question. You can see there that the `case` is indeed working, despite that.

Comment: I mean to put the console.log statement into the *code*. It will not work in the console. When you run `console.log(DialogTitle)` in the console, it is trying to refer to a global variable named `DialogTitle`, which does not exist.

Comment: Derp. Trying that.

Comment: Indeed the `console.log(DialogTitle)` outputs `ƒ`. But still, how does this switch statement work?

Comment: It checks if the type `===` the function `DialogTitle` (which was imported at the top of the file), and if so it goes into the first case. If not, it checks if the type `===` the function `DialogDescription`, and enters that case. And so on. None of the values are `undefined`, they're each independent functions, so this check works fine and identifies which type of component was received (among a limited set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are seeing in the debugger is *not* the code being executed. What you see as `Container.tsx` is actually probably just a snippet of compiled pure JS in a huge `bundle.js` somewhere.

Typescript code requires compilation before the browser can read it. As part of this step, it also generates source maps which map the compiled code back to your original source files. Webpack or whatever bundler you're using probably does it's own compilation then, and makes new source maps.

For the most part this makes it easier to debug, but it isn't perfect. So what you think is `DialogTitle` probably is an identifier that got transformed somehow during compilation, minification, obfuscation, bundling, etc...

You can [disable source maps entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools) to get a clearer view if what's going on, though the code your debugging will probably start to look pretty cryptic.

Source maps usually do work just fine, but not all tools can generate them perfectly, I've observed.

---

As for how the switch statement works, functions have an identity which can be queried by a switch statement.

For example, this works because `MyComponent` is assigned either `A` or `B` and each `case`  can test that.

```
function A() { return <>A</> }
function B() { return <>B</> }

const MyComponent = Math.random() > 0.5 ? A : B

switch(MyComponent) {
  case A: console.log('got A'); break
  case B: console.log('got B'); break
}
// logs "got A" or "got B"
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCzAVwDsNgJa4BBACgEo4BvOImalGYAeAHwthAelFwAvlToMmcAEKcefJAKFwxKqTPmVyaJgGd4AWQCeAYVyRaSWvAC8cSyhgALAHRQUWgATXHUZAAZfAFY4AH5WOAAuVQoKMwB3YBg0bzYbe3AmZxgubgo4ODQUMyRWZNNaMwgAGyRfZogAczZ8Toh4FnwOAG44ACMiFABrcsrq2pV68xa2ju7e-tUh0YnUGfJZIA)

---

> In the code I referenced, it's `switch(child.type)` and I don't understand how `child.type` is compared against a function? `child.type` is itself a function, but I'm still very confused about how that comparison evaluates to `true`.

This delves into react internals a bit, so I can't vouch for *why* but this appears to be what's going on.

When a component is rendered it returns a `JSX.Element` object. This object appears to have a `type` property on it that is a reference to the component that rendered that JSX.

For example:

```
function A() { return <>A</> }
console.log(<A />);
```

Yields this in the console:

[image: jsx result in console]

This means that rendered JSX remembers the component that rendered it via that `type` property. And this loop here checks to see if any children were rendered with specific components that may need special handling.

[Here's a minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ully-v8kpd1?file=/src/App.tsx) that's closer to what your original snippet is actually doing.

Comment: You're right, it's apparently a source mapping issue - but can you help point me towards how this kind of switch statement can work with a `function` as the case value and help me get to a full answer for this?

Comment: Functions have an identity that a switch statement can test. See my update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit! That all makes great sense, but I'm still stuck on a single point. | In the code I referenced, it's `switch(child.type)` and I don't understand how `child.type` is compared against a `function`? `child.type` is itself a function, but I'm still very confused about how that comparison evaluates to `true`.

Comment: That's based on how react renders and serializes JSX. It's just looking for JSX generated from components that need extra handling. See my update.