# How to see the final compile css file when we use sass in react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm using SASS in my React project. I need to see the final compiled CSS file from that SASS.
When i go to:

[image]

I can see the SCSS but where is the **CSS** one?

**I mean the compiled version of index.scss or App.scss which will be index.css and app.css.**

P.S. i can find it at my build folder in my project, but rather see it in the inspect page at the browser.

Comment: Hi Sina, this would depend on the configuration of this project, is the repo public? could you share the link?

Comment: hey @MarioPerez thanks for the reply, I just started a new project via create-react-app, then installed sass and changed app.css to App.scss and the same for index .css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable source maps in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002087/disable-source-maps-in-chrome-devtools)

Comment: @AndyRay   this will just remove the rest of the files but still, I have that index.scss, but what I need is the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ you could add an env variable in your .env file

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

and then rebuild/restart your application

Comment: this will just remove the rest of the files but still, I have that index.scss, but what I need is the CSS file